# Problema al cargar el response de la petición AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap

Tengo un problema con un formulario de registro que estoy programando en *PHP + jQuery + HTML + Bootstrap*. Estoy utilizando la plantilla de `bootstrap` y el control `selectpicker` de `bootstrap-select`. Hasta hace unos días estaba funcionando todo bien... De repente, para cargar los `selectpicker` desde una petición *AJAX* me salta un error en la consola del navegador:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).selectpicker is not a function(…)

La petición de *AJAX* está bien, ya que entra en el `success`. El problema es cuando quiero cargar el response de la petición en el `selectpicker`:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "controller.php",
    data: {
        accion: function() {return "cargarDeptos";} 
    },
   success: function(response) {
        $('#cboDeptos').html(response).fadeIn();
        $('#cboDeptos').selectpicker('refresh');
    }
});
```

En el principio del archivo hago una referencia a los archivos `js` y `css` correspondientes en el siguiente orden:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../resources/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../resources/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../resources/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../resources/js/utils.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../resources/js/numeric.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../resources/js/validate.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../resources/css/modal-login.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../resources/css/bootstrap.css">    
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../resources/css/bootstrap-theme.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../resources/css/login.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../resources/css/bootstrap-select.css">
```

Lo raro de todo esto es que si yo cargo anteriormente una página llamada `home.php`, que también utiliza *jQuery*, y luego voy al formulario que me da problemas si funciona todo bien, pero recargo la página de registro y vuelve a aparecer el problema. Parece como si por un momento se quedara cargado *jQuery*, pero al reiniciar desaparece.

Comment: trata de utilizar esto `$('#cboDeptos').selectpicker('render').selectpicker('refresh');`

Comment: Gracias por responder!! pero no me funciono eso!

Answer (score 1):

¿Estás seguro de que tu código se está ejecutando después de haber cargado el *plugin*?

Quiero decir, que sea algo como esto (por ejemplo):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "controller.php",
        data: {
            accion: function() {return "cargarDeptos";} 
        },
        success: function(response) {
            $('#cboDeptos').html(response).fadeIn();
            $('#cboDeptos').selectpicker('refresh');
        }
    });
});
```

Lo que puede estar pasando es que al momento de ejecutar el *AJAX*, no está listo el *plugin*, y por ende, te dice que `selectpicker` no está definido.

Answer (score 0):

Es posible que de algún modo se esté cargado jQuery dos veces? una antes de cargar el plugin y otra después? en ocasiones si esto pasa te puede des-registrar los plugins.